# Mavericks OS X Server : Wiki : Copy & Paste Tables?

Tags: macos, server.app

How can I transfer a table in a wiki page to another page? (...without copy&paste for each cell separately)

I use OS X Server on Mavericks. In the wiki I would like to copy a table from one wiki to another wiki. I went into edit mode for the source and destination page. Then I marked the table, pressed Cmd+C and in the destination page pressed Cmd+V. The result is a table with another table "over it" and both are messed up. I tried source page not in edit mode, but it doesn't work.

What methods can be used to copy a table that's on a wiki page to another page?

EDIT:

It looks like copy & paste works well within one Safari instance, but fails, when I try to copy the content out of a VMWare Fusion VM. (Copy in the guest and paste in the host.)

An example for the result:

[image: Wrong table after paste]

I will try to access the Server instance in the VM from outside the VM (didn't want that so far) and see whether copy&paste works, when I use a single instance of Safari to do that.

EDIT#2:

I tried it using a single Safari instance and it worked well. I can enter edit mode in the two wiki pages, select all content from the source page, press Cmd+C and in the destination page press Cmd+V and the content is added nicely and beautifully. So it seems the clipboard transfer out of the VM breaks it for Safari.

I will play with this during the next days - for now it works for me.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It is the Wiki software which comes with OS X Server (I use 3.1.2) - it is not related to wikipedia or the like. I have to leave the desk for now, but when I'm back I will add some screenshots.

Comment: Ate you using the original WYSIWYG or others.

Comment: I use the standard setup. I added some more details to the question.